# How to find which link was selected in gsp

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have many links that directs to the same form. If I select link x I wanted the form to add another field. If not the forms stays the same.

I have tried to set a param but that didn't pass the value. Is there any way that i can find out which link is selected in gsp?

I have tried

```
<g:link class="btn" elementId="editBtn"
    controller="plant" action="create" 
    model="[linkClicked:'true']" 
params="[return: ret.id,linkClicked:'true']" data-modal="createPlant">
                    xxxxxxxxxx
                </g:link>
```

Comment: You should be able to add an extra param to the link's URL and then detect that when rendering the form. You may need to catch and pass through the param value as a model attribute in your controller. Please show us what code you have tried already.

Comment: I have updated my question and I've tried model but "model" is not a key word of link. That didn't work either...(model is key word of a render)

Answer (score 1):

The params approach should work, but you would need to forward those params to the view.

```
<g:link controller="plant" action="create" params="[createPlant: true]" />
```

The controller

```
class PlantController {

  def create() {
     def createPlant = params.createPlant ? true : false
     [createPlant: createPlant]
  }
}
```

the view

```
<g:if test="${creatPlant}">
   <!-- show extra form element -->
</g:if>
```

Something like that anyway.